How to force the import of users from LDAP in Liferay 7.4.3.102?
I am trying to configure Liferay 7.4.3.102. I am using a Docker image from the official repository.
I have configured LDAP in Liferay in the section
Control Panel -> Instance Settings -> LDAP.

Of course, I enabled user import in the import section, enabled LDAP in the various sections, and added the LDAP server in the Servers section. Here, upon clicking on Test LDAP`Connection, the following message appears
Liferay has successfully connected to the LDAP server,
clicking on Test LDAP Users shows up all the users and their information, and clicking on Test LDAP Groups shows up all the groups.
However, going to the
Control Panel -> Users -> Users and Organizations.

only the Test user appears, while there is no record of the users to be imported from LDAP.
Is there any way to force the users to be imported?
